# $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3}{n}(1+\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+3}}+\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+6}}+...+\sqrt{\frac{n}{4n-3}})$

Tags: limits

fine the limits :

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3}{n}(1+\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+3}}+\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+6}}+...+\sqrt{\frac{n}{4n-3}})$$

My Try :

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3}{n}(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{n}}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{6}{n}}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{3(n-1)}{n}}})\\$$

Now ?

Comment: Now integrate $ \int_{1}^{4} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} $.

Comment: @SangchulLee. why ?

Comment: Because that is what you get when you take $n\to\infty$ to your Riemann sum.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac3n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sqrt{\frac n{n+3k}}=\frac3n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sqrt{\frac1{1+\frac{3k}n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}3\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt{1+3x}}\,dx$$

Comment: I guess the upper bound id $1$, not $3$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Of course, good catch. Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio, Usually I am not that nitpicking, but this time I was a bit worried that all three answers made the same mistake. Thank you for accepting my suggestion!

Comment: @SangchulLee What wasn't, imo, nitpicking but actually observing an ugly, stupid mistake. I guess that $\;3\;$ there inside the square root misled us all...:)

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \frac { 3 }{ n } \left( 1+\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 1+\frac { 3 }{ n }  }  } +\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 1+\frac { 6 }{ n }  }  } +...+\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 1+\frac { 3(n-1) }{ n }  }  }  \right) =\\ =3\lim _{ n\to \infty  } \sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ \frac { 1 }{ n } \left( \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 1+\frac { 3\left( k-1 \right)  }{ n }  }  }  \right)  } =3\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \frac { dx }{ \sqrt { 1+3x }  }  } =\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ \frac { d\left( 1+3x \right)  }{ \sqrt { 1+3x }  }  } =\\ =2$$

Comment: I guess the upper bound id $1$, not $3$.